# jqgrid: JQuery UI fonts ok for Grid but totally oversized for Form

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am starting to apply JQuery UI themes to my jqGrid /java application. When I apply a theme (cupertino, smoothness, etc), the results are ok for the grid itself. But when I open the Edit Form, fonts are totally oversized - I can't even fit 2 input fields in the default form size. Here are my links in the main page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.min.css" />

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Am I missing some links or scripts, or should I remove some?

Comment: I made jqgrid the last css file to be loaded and the form fonts are ok, but there is garbage in the form background (lines, shades), and the datepicker pop-up is still overblown and ugly ..

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had downloaded all JQuery UI themes and was trying them one by one by linking the original CSS theme files. When I downloaded one theme and generated the corresponding 'custom' theme files with the provided online tool (at JQuery UI web site), everything worked and looked as expected.